# Why is this proof wrong? $2^i = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, fake-proofs

If $i=-1^\frac{1}{2}$, then $2^i$ could be written as $2^{{-1}^{1/2}}$.
By the multiplicative law of exponents, this should be equal to $2^{-1/2}$, which is $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$.

This doesn't feel right. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $a^{b^c} \neq a^{bc} =(a^b)^c$. Also at least write $(-1)^{1/2}$ and not $-1^{1/2}$ (altough it is still a problematic notation).

Comment: $i = (-1)^{\frac12}$, not $i=-1^{\frac12}$. Also, which "law" of exponents did you use to conclude that $2^{-1^{\frac12}}=2^{-\frac12}$? This is very much incorrect.

Comment: For a correct result, use $z^w = e^{w \log(z)}$, which holds for complex numbers $w, z \in \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument seems to be $$2^i = 2^{\left(-1^{1/2}\right)} \color{red}{\stackrel{???}=} (2^{-1})^{1/2} = \left(\frac12\right)^{1/2} = \frac{\sqrt2}2.$$

But this is wrong, because even in straightforward cases $$a^{\left(b^c\right)} \ne \left(a^b\right)^c = a^{bc}.$$  Consider $$2^{\left(2^3\right)} \ne \left(2^2\right)^3 = 2^{2\cdot 3}$$ for example.  The left side is $2^8=256$, but the right side is $2^6=64$.

There can be tricky issues with the $a^b$ notation when $a$ or $b$ is not a real number, but this is not one of the tricky cases.  One can define $$2^x = \left(e^{\ln(2)}\right)^x = e^{x\ln(2)}$$ where $\ln$ is the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) function.  The actual value of $\ln(2)$ is approximately $0.693$.

Then by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), $$e^{ix} = \cos (x) + i\sin (x),$$ of which perhaps you have heard, we get:

$$\begin{align}
2^i & = \cos(\ln 2) + i\sin(\ln 2) \\
 & \approx 0.769 + 0.639i.\\\end{align}$$

I suppose that this strange-looking result feels no better than the one you (correctly) rejected. Its actual meaning is a profound and extremely important matter.  I'd like to recommend a book for you to pursue it further if you want to, but none is coming to mind.  Tristan Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* is superb, but may be too advanced for you at this stage.

Comment: Thanks, that example is very helpful. I was under the assumption that that rule works for all numbers, based on the first example I thought of: $3^4^{1/2} = 3^2$.

Comment: That was an unlucky choice!  That example only works because $4^{1/2} = 4\cdot\frac12$.

Comment: @HabeebM You should avoid assuming that a rule works for every number based on one single example. This is bound to lead to many mistakes down the road.

Comment: Yeah I was very tired when I thought of this and still am kind of new to complex numbers. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

To start with, it is problematic to try to use notation of the form $x^s$ and let $s$ be an object that is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. There is no consistent and unambiguous way to define this notation for $s\in\mathbb{C}$ without making the notation very unsatisfactory in general, so which "laws" of exponents hold in a given circumstances is very much dependent on context, and is purely a matter of semantic convenience, not a matter of actual mathematical truth.

That being said, one reasonable definition that people commonly use (though not used by mathematicians, because again, it is ultimately problematic) is that $z^{\zeta}=\exp(\zeta\log(z))$, where $\log(z)$ is understood to be short notation for $\ln(\left|z|\right)+\mathrm{atan}2\left(\mathrm{Im}(z),\mathrm{Re}(z)\right)i$ for $z\neq0$. *In that context,* $2^i=\exp(i\log(2))=\exp(i\ln(2))=\cos(\ln(2))+\sin(\ln(2))i$. Unlike the notation $2^i$, the notation $\exp(i\log(2))$ is not problematic, since $\exp$, $\ln$, and $\mathrm{atan}2$ are unambiguously, rigorously defined functions in complex analysis.